# Perl Split at Double Hyphen or Alphanumber

Tags: regex, perl, split

I would like to split a string in Perl at the double hyphen "--" or alphanumeric character (a-z/0-9).

Sample inputs are:

```
98.0 234.2 34.2 first
234.3 -- 3.5 third
 -- -- -- fourth
23.3 5.4 100.00 second
```

I tried doing `my @linesplit = split(/[--\s]+/, $line);` but this does not work. I'm having trouble matching a regex to take a group of possible splits.

i'm expecting an output such as:

```
@linesplit = [23.3 ,5.4 ,100.00 ,second]
@linesplit = [--, -- ,-- ,fourth]
```

Comment: @sfr , what is the expected content of `linesplit`? Include it in the question.

Comment: @ikegami updated

Comment: You are conflating a split (deleting and separating what you do NOT want) with a capturing (capturing what you DO want.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to want to split on whitespace.

```
my @fields = split ' ', $line;
```

Comment: I'm not the asker, but having a working code (either in the question or in this answer) would help me and other to learn Perl.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Just prepend `my $line = "23.3 5.4 100.00 second";`

Comment: sorry, I meant something I can use from the shell as in `cat thefile | perl -e 'whatever'`. Feel free not to answer if you think this goes beyond answering.

Comment: `while (<>) { my @fields = split; ... }`

Comment: `cat thefile |` is a sucky way to write `<thefile`

Comment: totally agree, but I just wanted to mean that the input comes from a pipe.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis but what output?  if you split a line into fields, what do you want done with the fields on output?

Comment: @ysth, one could pretty print the array in a way that shows that the split happened as desired.